# What is the difference between image and package directory in Yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I wrote a basic hello world recipe

```
DESCRIPTION = "Simple helloworld C application"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "file://userprog.c file://ReadMe.txt"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_compile() {
    ${CC} -DUSE_SYSCALL userprog.c ${LDFLAGS} -o userprog
}

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 userprog ${D}${bindir}
    install -d ${D}${docdir}
    install -m 0644 ReadMe.txt ${D}${docdir}
}
```

After, looking at the WORKDIR, the contents of 'package' and 'image' folder are same.

$ tree image/

```
image/
└── usr
    ├── bin
    │   └── userprog
    └── share
        └── doc
            └── ReadMe.txt
```

$ tree package

```
package
└── usr
    ├── bin
    │   └── userprog
    └── share
        └── doc
            └── ReadMe.txt
```

What is the difference between both folders, I know image folder is controlled in do_install task, what about in package folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`images/` is for staging install dir, something like `make install DESTDIR=<..>`

`package` is for `do_package` task which is then further split into individual output packages in `packages-split`,

even though the content looks similar context is different, since it operates on `PACKAGES` and `FILES` variables, and if the files are not mentioned in these variables it won't copy those from `image/` into `package/` it is described in detail in [Yocto project manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#structure-build-tmp-work-tunearch-recipename-version)